# Whose side Rachel and Leah were on?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, parsha-torah-portion

According to Ariz"l's tradition (*as described in R' Moshe Luria's book "Beis Gnozay" on the Torah, parshas "Vayetse"*), **the sequence of Yaacov's marriages** (Rachel first and then Leah) **was of great importance**, dealing with the Seider of the Geulah, the proper order of Moshiachs, etc, that Lavan planned to undermine that and harm the Jewish nation for generations (hence the everlasting fights between the Tribes, for example).

Rachel and Leah are presented throughout all interpreters and Midrashim as Zadkaniot and having Ruach HaKodesh. However, in fact, they helped Lavan with his wicked plan, and, therefore, deeply betrayed Yaacov.

How could they conspire with their wicked father against Jacob (and God) to undermine the proper order of the Geulah?

Comment: What is your source for your first sentence?

Comment: I don't get the first paragraph exactly, or how it relates to the question. Couldn't you just ask if they were righteous, why they played along with a lie?

Comment: I heard it from a prominent Hassidisher scholar, who explains some Drash on the magnitude of Lavan's wicked plan.

Comment: Sources should be edited into posts.

Comment: To repeat my question, are you just looking for an explanation of why they participated in a lie if they were righteous?

Comment: Of course, why would they do such terrible thing to their beloved Tzadik?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by beloved tzaddik, and I don't see how your previous comment clarifies anything. My question is: if your question is simply why good people would lie, why muddle the question with a seemingly irrelevant, distracting, and confusing first paragraph.

Comment: @AlBerko Which rabbi did you hear it from? And did he say it was from the Arizal or did you make that conclusion? [Edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/87229/edit) to clarify the source. And if it is from the Arizal, from where?

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question? It's a valid question, they only thing is that source material needs to be added. +1

Comment: Lavan probably forced Leah into it. Seeing that it was going to happen anyway Rochel gave her the siminim for her to avoid embarrassment

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127034/do-commentaries-address-question-the-morality-of-leah-and-rachels-actions-again , related/dupe?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the Ari Zal (please post sources). But when Esav failed and faded, it became necessary to marry Leah to Yaakov, to build Shivtei Yisrael. Lavan had the wrong intentions but it needed to happen, and Yaakov would surely not have cooperated.
According to the Midrash, Leah desperately wanted to marry Yaakov (instead of Esav), crying and praying till her eyes got messed up. She was *able* to marry Yaakov because of her father's plan, and because Yaakov himself had given her an opening by what he had himself done to fool his own father, according to that same Midrash (see [https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127034](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127034/do-commentaries-address-question-the-morality-of-leah-and-rachels-actions-again)).
I think all of this is a consequence of the situation. It seems unreasonable to treat that as "taking sides". Perhaps it was inevitable once Yaakov had fooled his father.
To me it sounds like asking, Wouldn't things have been much better if Avraham Avinu had not said, "במה אדע כי אירשנה"? - We wouldn't have had to go down to Mitzrayim...! Our Avos were incredibly holy people, but not yet perfect. Fixing their almost invisible imperfections is part of the path that we have followed ever since.

Comment: Why would Yaakov not cooperate to build Shivtei Yisrael by marrying Leah? I feel like this is half an answer.

Comment: Certainly that wasn't his current plan; he made a deal for Rachel. Probably Leah thought so too. Could be I'm answering in a pshat mode (since the question is just as good there) instead of working within the Arizal's picture? I don't know how to write Midrashim!

Comment: Your answer does not address the question at all. Please rewrite or delete it.