# Why did Rachel cooperated with Lea in deceiving Jacob?

Tags: tanach

Rachel is considered one of Jewish mothers and known in her holiness. Why did she cooperate with Lea and gave her the signs without informing Jacob. Moreover, she knew how eager (spiritually) Jacob to marry her. She knew how much time he worked for her. So how come that she practically did such a did. In addition, it is considered as a mercy. When she asks mercy for Israel nation she reminds G-d this? Isn't it cruel to do such a thing for Jacob?

Comment: They say if Yakov knew her reasonings he would've agreed.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87229/whose-side-rachel-and-leah-were-on?r=SearchResults&s=1|35.8678

Comment: It appears that the Biblical narrative doesn't agree with you - Yaakov didn't plan to marry Leah, he worked two terms for Rachel - one willingly and one unwillingly.

Comment: Please state your question clearly - the title says "why she cooperated" and the body asks differently.