Is it all Leah's doing?
As we know from the commentaries and midrashim, Leah's eyes were weak from praying to Hashem to not have to marry Esav. If she had, her job would have been to cause him to turn into a "good guy". If that had happened, all history would have been different.
Her tefilot were answered and she was zoche to marry Yaacov instead.
The end result is the events that transpired: Esav had to lose the right of firstborn, which was given to Yaacov. Esav remained a "bad guy", instead of becoming the fourth Av Yisrael, and we had to go through this millennia-long struggle, swapping power with Esav, being treated "like dust" by him for most of history.
I would like to find any sources that analyze this. Did all of the above happen because of her prayers and Hashem's love for her? Did she know this would be the result? Would this have happened some other way (we have so many reasons given for the galuyot after all). What's the significance of this?

A possible component for the answer is probably here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87229/whose-side-rachel-and-leah-were-on/144122#144122

@YDJ it's an interesting idea, but it effectively undermines the premise of the question so it's not ideal as an answer.

Maybe. Lavan also knew about Leah's worries. She must have spoken to him about it. BY the way, we learn Chumash and nobody asks whether Leah and Rachel had a healthy relationship with their father. Would they have to speak to him about their worries? What about their mother?

@YDJ https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.29.12.2

@Heshy i meant if they had good relationship with their mother.

Who says she would have been able to change him?  I've heard that that's not a recipe for a healthy relationship.

@Heshy I've heard that too, from secular sources. Therefore I don't know what to do with it, even though it sounds wise. Her ability to change Esav lies in her connection to tears and teshuva, in the sources

I think the troubles are because of Lavan. It is like Roman emperor learning the Torah to identify in it a punishment for 10 righteous rabbis. So it is Lavan, who had 4 wonderful daughters and a big hatred of Yaakov, thus Lavan arranged the deal so that they would not get along.

What about Yaakov's doing, who locked Dina in a chest, to prevent her from being seen by - and married to - Esav?

@TamirEvan just like super mario, I've been +1up'd

Esav lost his bichora way before leah was even born.

"Her tefilot were answered and she was zoche to marry Yaacov instead." According to Baba Batra 123a, not only that, but her intent was rewarded, too: "והיינו דכתיב: 'וירא ה׳ כי שנואה לאה' – מאי 'שנואה'? ... ראה הקדוש ברוך הוא ששנואין מעשה עשו בפניה, 'ויפתח את רחמה'."

Maybe the everlasting war with Amalek is because we rejected Timna, Eliphaz's pilegesh and the mother of Amalek, as a convert. https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.99b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Regarding the point brought up in the comments about the chance of Leah changing Eisav, and why it was different that Yaakov being punished for hiding Dinah. Rav Yosef Sorotzkin in his Meged Yosef writes that if Eisav would have married Dinah, Yaakov would have looked after, and ensured, that Dinah would not have been influenced by Eisav, and on the contrary be a good influence on him. Leah would not have such a "guardian" and therefore the danger to her spirituality would be much greater. She was therefore never punished for her tfillos.

Yes it's explicit in a midrash in Bereishis Rabbah 70:16:

וְהָיְתָה בּוֹכָה וְאוֹמֶרֶת יְהִי רָצוֹן שֶׁלֹא אֶפֹּל בְּגוֹרָלוֹ שֶׁל רָשָׁע. אָמַר רַב הוּנָא קָשָׁה הִיא הַתְּפִלָּה שֶׁבִּטְלָה אֶת הַגְּזֵרָה, וְלֹא עוֹד אֶלָּא שֶׁקָּדְמָה לַאֲחוֹתָה
She would weep and say: ‘May it be His will that I will not fall to the lot of that wicked man.’ Rav Huna said: Prayer is powerful, as it nullified the decree. Moreover, she preceded her sister.


If anything, according to my question, this took her decree and put it on the rest of the Jewish people. The decree of thousands of years of war with Esav?
